# Mongo aggregate by month returns null

Tags: mongodb

I have date in my model

```
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
},
```

I add date in db creating it from separate fields year, month, date

```
...
    date: new Date(year, Number(month) - 1, date),
...
```

In MongoDB compass I see it as

```
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1670011200000"
    }
  },
```

I'm trying to aggregate collection data by month

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      ...
    },
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      month: {
        $month: {
          $toDate: "$date"
        }
      },
    }
  }
])
```

But I receive

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6302338f4d8104216b0e889a"),
    "month": null
  },
```

Why my date returns **null**?

Comment: Your `$project` stage looks correct. Could you please provide the whole aggregation query?

Comment: `$month: "$date"` should suffice, no need to convert, **if** $date is still available after $group stage. Show what's in there

Comment: Thanks both, problem was with grouping, I didn't add month in this stage